# Adaptable Hyperlink between documents

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I'm looking for a way to create a hyperlink on a tracking sheet that will recognize a part of a document name to link to.

for example if I have a list of forms that needs to be audited (numbered 1 thru 10) in one column of a sheet that refer to docmuents that are saved in another folder, can I use a formula that will recognize the name of the forms to be audited as they are created and automatically link them?

It would like this (in an excel format)

(folder 1, excel workbook1)

Column 1  --  Column 2

Doc 1    --   Mr. Auditor

Doc 2    --   Mrs. Auditor

Doc 3    --   Dr. Auditor

(folder 2, individual workbooks)

Financial Doc 1.xlxs

Financial Doc 2.xlxs

Financial Doc 3.xlxs

.

The tracking sheet will be initially be numbered 1-80 regardless of how many docs exist in the other folder, but as the Financial Docs are added if they keep a consistant naming convention I would like their respective position in column 1 of the tracking sheet to automatically link to that doc.

If this is possible, or if it requires a different method I would be eager to learn it. I would be able to use this to organise a large amount of information on simple sheets.

Thank you all.